# Position an SVG text element relative to a preceding text element, without hard x/y coordinates?

Tags: html, css, svg

Is it possible for an SVG text element to simply flow inline after a previous text (or other) element, such that the x/y position of the element is determined solely by where the previous element left off, much the same way one HTML `<span>` element will  flow after a previous `<span>` element, adjusting its position according to however much width the previous span required?

```
        <text id="time" x="50" y="105" text-anchor="middle">--:--:--</text>
        <text id="dut1-label" text-anchor="start"> ΔUT1: </text>
        <text id="dut1" text-anchor="start">±--- ms</text>
```

Since the time value displayed above may or may not be followed by an AM/PM indicator, I'd rather the small notation for ΔUT1 following the time simply flows naturally after the right edge of the time, wherever that might happen to end up, and without adding the notation to the text element for the time itself, so the time alone, not counting the notation, remains centered.

Surrendering to hard-coded coordinates, this is the result I get:

[image: screen shot]

I'm hoping to get a similar result, but without the hard-coded x/y positions. I'm pretty sure I can do it with some JavaScript code, of course, but I'm hoping for a solution that depends solely on SVG and CSS.

Comment: check about foreingObject https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject

Comment: @Mayra, I can see how that might help in some situations, but in this case either the `<foreignObject>` would still need to know how to position itself relative to the time display, or the time display would have to become part of the `<foreignObject>` too, in which case positioning and sizing the `<foreignObject>` in its SVG context would become problematic.

Comment: Use one <text> element with multiple <tspan> children.

Comment: @Robert, the problem if I do that is that I don't see a way to center the time *only on the time itself* and not, instead, the full width of the text including the caption being centered instead.

Comment: Then you'd have to position things individually with javascript and getComputedTextLength()

Comment: @Robert, that's what I'm settling for for now, but I was hoping for a better solution. What's a bit awkward about the adjustments in JavaScript is that the only runtime width info I can figure out how to obtain is in pixel values, whereas the `x` and `y` attributes of the SVG elements need to be set in viewBox values, so scaling has to be computed (I'll post the code I'm using below as an answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is the non-ideal JavaScript (well, TypeScript to be precise) solution I'm going with for now, unless I find something better:

```
  private adjustDut1Position(): void {
    const viewWidth = (this.clock as any)?.viewBox?.baseVal?.width ?? 172;
    const r0 = this.clock.getBoundingClientRect();
    const scale = viewWidth / r0.width;
    const r1 = this.timeCaption.getBoundingClientRect();
    const r2 = this.dut1Label.getBoundingClientRect();
    const labelX = (r1.x + r1.width - r0.x) * scale;
    const captionX = labelX + r2.width * scale;

    this.dut1Label.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', labelX.toString());
    this.dut1Caption.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', captionX.toString());
  }
```

There's additional logic beyond this as well to schedule when the position adjustments are performed.

Fairly shortly, the running results will be posted at https://weather.shetline.com (although the real application is for a [Raspberry Pi-based desktop clock](https://github.com/kshetline/aw-clock), not as a website).